# nVidia openGL fails to display simple COLOR_INDEX texture

Tags: opengl, nvidia, texture-mapping

I have my first simple OpenGL program to display 2D images using OpenGL. I'm using an index-based image, calling `glTexImage2D(.. GL_RGB, ... GL_COLOR_IMAGE...)`
This is working as expected on an ATI card.
Having swapped to an nVidia card, I see a black quad instead of my image. Given that it works on the ATI I guess the code is basically correct - but maybe I have missed a setting - or maybe the card doesn't support what I'm doing (?!)

First the Setup code (I'm using Qt btw, so there's probably some context calls I'm missing):-

```
glClearColor( 0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 0); // background color

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);      // 4-byte pixel alignment

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR ); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL );
```

Here's the code to set the texture :-

```
GLfloat Greys[256];
GLfloat Ones[256];
for( int I(0); I < 256; ++I )
{
  Greys[I] = (GLfloat)I/256;
  Ones[I] = 1.0;
}

makeCurrent();
glPixelMapfv( GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_R, 256, Greys );
glPixelMapfv( GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_G, 256, Greys );
glPixelMapfv( GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_A, 256, Ones );

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, m_pImage->size().width(), m_pImage->size().height(), 0, GL_COLOR_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pImage->bits() );
```

Here's the display code

```
glLoadIdentity();
// Get the camera in the right place
glRotatef( 180, 1, 0, 0 );
// Apply the Pan(Offset), and Zoom
glTranslatef( m_Offset.x(), m_Offset.y(), 0);
glScalef( m_Zoom, m_Zoom, 1 );

// Display the image texture mapped to a rectangle
glColor3f( 1,1,0 );

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f( 0, 0 );  glVertex3f( 0, 0, 10 );
glTexCoord2f( 1, 0 );   glVertex3f( ImSize.width(), 0, 10 );
glTexCoord2f( 1, 1 );   glVertex3f( ImSize.width(), ImSize.height(), 10 );
glTexCoord2f( 0, 1 );   glVertex3f( 0, ImSize.height(), 10 );
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I also display the same image in full colour, in a separate window, using a straight RGB - RGB call to glTexImage2D. So I'm confident the dimensions are acceptable.

If I remove the call to glTexImage2D then I get a yellow quad as expected. Thus I suspect I have a problem with my calls to set the colour LUTs.

Board is an ASUS GeForce 210 silent
Windows XP 32 bit. 
nVidia Drivers 6.14.13.681 (9-23-2012), R306.81 (branch: r304_70-122)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you test for OpenGL error codes? You may use this code: https://gist.github.com/4144988 – regarding color index formats? I wouldn't be surprised if it simply wasn't supported by the driver. Nobody uses color index formats these days. If you want to draw a palleted texture, upload the pallete into a 1D RGB texture and the color indexed image into a single channel (GL_RED or GL_LUMINANCE, depending on the OpenGL version) 2D texture and use the value as index into the pallete texture.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf. I did check for errors - and stripped them out above for clarity (I used gluErrorString to translate for me). But they all returned zero anyway.

Comment: Yes ! 

The answer is to use

    glPixelTransferi( GL_MAP_COLOR, TRUE );
    glPixelMapfv( GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_R, 256, Greys );
    :

I thought I had tried this - but I think I had incorrectly tried `glEnable(GL_MAP_COLOR)` or something - which _did_ give me an error. Thanks to datenwolf, I tried again, to reproduce the error, but I managed to do it a bit more carefully this time.

Of course this code is correct and the nVidia card behaves logically, whilst the ATI board's behavour is probably not to spec, but displays decent 'undefined' behavour.